# Why I am not able to run executables from shell script

Tags: shell, ubuntu, executable

I have a shell script which calls for different executables from it.
The shell script and the executables are within same directory and I am trying to run it from there. Still, on running, I get the error, "executable" not found- No file/directory exists.
What should I do???

Comment: How do you call the other executables? Is you current directory part of your PATH?

Answer (score 1):

First, You need to provide permission to the File :

```
chmod +x filename
```

Then, execute the binary file by,

```
./filename
```

Answer (score 0):

The current directory is typically not in your command path, for security reasons. You need to provide the path explicitly, that is

```
./mycommand
```

instead of

```
mycommand
```

(Keep in mind, though, that this will break if you run the script from a different directly. `./mycommand` is relative to the directory you run from, not the directory where the script is stored.)